# Issue with special characters in Python subprocess

Tags: python, awk, subprocess

I translated this bash one-liner:

```
awk '/\]:$/{pno=NR;prec=$0;next} pno && !(/^I/ && NR==pno+1){print prec; pno=0} 1' filename2 > filename1
```

into this Python code

```
with open('filename1', 'w') as f:
    call(['awk', '/\\\]:$/{pno=NR;prec=$0;next} pno && !(/^I/ && NR==pno+1){print prec; pno=0} 1', 'filename2'], stdout=f)
```

The output file, however, is empty, and it is not when I use the bash.

With this:

```
call(['awk', r"'/\]:$/{pno=NR;prec=$0;next} pno && !(/^I/ && NR==pno+1){print prec; pno=0} 1'"], stdout=f)
```

I get

> awk: '/]:$/{pno=NR;prec=$0;next} pno && !(/^I/ && NR==pno+1){print
>   prec; pno=0} 1' awk: ^ invalid char ''' in expression

**Sample Input file:**

```
Interval: [ some_value some_value1]:
Interval: [ some_value some_value2]:
some text here1 
some text here2
some text here3
some text here4
Interval: [ some_value some_value3]:
Interval: [ some_value some_value4]:
Interval: [ some_value some_value5]:
Interval: [ some_value some_value6]:
some text here5
some text here6
some text here7
some text here8
Interval: [ some_value some_value7]:
Interval: [ some_value some_value8]:
```

**Sample Output File:**

```
Interval: [ some_value some_value2]:
some text here1
some text here2
some text here3
some text here4
Interval: [ some_value some_value6]:
some text here5
some text here6
some text here7
some text here8
```

Comment: For this kind of string, use the raw string notation: `r"abc\def"`. It may prevent mistakes, and will reduce overall complexity of understanding what you wrote.

Answer (score 2):

I bet you have an issue with your string conversion. Python version gives:

```
>>> print('/\\\]:$/{pno=NR;prec=$0;next} pno && !(/^I/ && NR==pno+1){print prec; pno=0} 1')
/\\]:$/{pno=NR;prec=$0;next} pno && !(/^I/ && NR==pno+1){print prec; pno=0} 1
```

While the shell version gives.

```
$ echo '/\]:$/{pno=NR;prec=$0;next} pno && !(/^I/ && NR==pno+1){print prec; pno=0} 1'
/\]:$/{pno=NR;prec=$0;next} pno && !(/^I/ && NR==pno+1){print prec; pno=0} 1
```

You can simplify this kind of stuff using raw string notation:

```
>>> print(r'/\]:$/{pno=NR;prec=$0;next} pno && !(/^I/ && NR==pno+1){print prec; pno=0} 1')
/\]:$/{pno=NR;prec=$0;next} pno && !(/^I/ && NR==pno+1){print prec; pno=0} 1
```

From the documentation:

> When an `r` or `R` prefix is present, backslashes are still used to quote the following character, but all backslashes are left in the string. For example, the string literal r"\n" consists of two characters: a backslash and a lowercase `n'. String quotes can be escaped with a backslash, but the backslash remains in the string; for example, r"\"" is a valid string literal consisting of two characters: a backslash and a double quote

So for your command:

```
call(['awk', r'/\]:$/{pno=NR;prec=$0;next} pno && !(/^I/ && NR==pno+1){print prec; pno=0} 1', filename2], stdout=f)
```

Comment: The single quotes `'` at the beginning and the end are not part of the actual string, bash removes them. You have to remove them as well.

Comment: I need the single quote. Why are them removed if it's a raw literal?

Comment: @Bob: they are not part of the string. Don't confuse a literal and the corresponding string object: there are no raw strings in memory -- raw string literal is just a notation to specify a string in Python source code.

Comment: well, I need single quote, that's a regular expression for awk

Comment: @Bob: awk does not see the single quotes if it is called in the shell either -- the shell strips the quotes.

Comment: The regular expression for `awk` does *not* include the single quote. The single quote is actually a delimiter for `bash`, telling it "hand what's inside over to awk without touching it".

Comment: with no single quote, it does not seem to terminate

Comment: If you're reusing the second line you copied in your question, you forgot to copy the filename argument, so it would just try to read from stdin.

Comment: I added the full command at the end of my answer, with correct quotes and arguments.

Comment: Can you post a sample input file then?

Comment: I edited your post by mistake. you are free to remove the example from yours.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91521/discussion-between-bob-and-spectras).

Comment: I'm not sure it will help but you can simplify your `awk` script to `awk '/]:$/{p=$0;next} p{print p;p=""}1'`